# How to make ng2-redux work with module lazy loading within an Angular 4 SPA?

Tags: angular, redux, lazy-loading

I am trying to introduce Redux within a small Angular 4 application that uses lazy loading (`loadChildren`) and I cannot make it work:

1) Relevant configuration (package.json)

```
"@angular/common": "4.4.5",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.5",
"@angular/core": "4.4.5",
"@angular/router": "4.4.5",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"ng2-redux": "^5.1.2",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
```

2) app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CustomCoreModule,
        NgReduxModule,
        AdvancedModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})

export class AppModuleShared {
    constructor(
        private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>,
        private devTools: DevToolsExtension) {

        var enhancers = isDevMode() ? [devTools.enhancer()] : [];
        console.log("AppModuleShared configuring store", this.ngRedux);
        ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE, [] /*, enhancers */);
    }
}
```

3) app-routing.module.ts (non-working)

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'advanced', loadChildren: () => AdvancedModule }, 
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

4) advanced.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, TodosModule, MessagingModule, AdvancedRoutingModule],
    declarations: [AngularMaterialTestComponent, ReduxTestComponent, TableTestComponent],
    providers: []
})
export class AdvancedModule { }
```

5) messaging.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [MessagesComponent],
  exports: [MessagesComponent]
})
export class MessagingModule { }
```

6) messages.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-messages',
    templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent {
    @select((s: IAppState) => s.messaging.messaging.newMessages) newMessages: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<{}>) {
        console.log("MessagesComponent started", this.ngRedux);
    }

    increment() {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT });
    }

    decrement() {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: DECREMENT });
    }
}
```

When I try to increment it fails with the following error:

> Dispatch failed: did you forget to configure your store?
>   https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux/blob/master/README.md#quick-start

`this.ngRedux` in this context is different from the one within `app.module.ts` (e.g. _store is null instead of having a value), so clearly I do not receive a proper instance.

If I change the `advanced` route within `app-routing.module.ts` to disable lazy-loading and directly load a component, it works (of course, this will blow up all the routing configured within `AdvancedModule`):

```
{ path: 'advanced', loadChildren: () => AdvancedModule, component: ReduxTestComponent }
```

My feeling is that performing store configuration like I did is too early, but I do not know when and how to perform the initialization for lazy loaded modules to benefit from it.

**Question:** How to make ng2-redux work with module lazy loading within an Angular 4 SPA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have once encountered a similar problem. Angular threw an error only when using *@select* but it wasn't obvious that therein lied the problem.

> **Replace @select with ngRedux.getState()**

---

You should also pass *IAppState* as interface for *NgRedux* in messages.component.ts instead of *{}*

**Try this code for messages.component.ts:**

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnDestroy {
    newMessages: any;

    constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
       this.storeUnsubscribe = ngRedux.subscribe(() => {
         this.newMessages = ngRedux.getState().messaging.messaging.newMessages;
       });
    }

    increment() {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT });
    }

    decrement() {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: DECREMENT });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Unsubscribe on component destroy to prevent memory leaks
        this.storeUnsubscribe();
    }
}
```

---

**If the above did not solve the problem:**

1. Make sure you only import *NgReduxModule* in app.module.ts
2. In a component, you only need *NgRedux* - do not import *NgReduxModule*
3. Update your question with the rest of package.json and imports in files

Comment: I will give it a try and provide feedback. Unfortunately, `() => AdvancedModule` syntax also fails when trying to publish the project (AOT does not support this syntax and requires a static syntax like a string or a component). Thanks.

Comment: Replace the anonymous function with a named function and it will be friendlier to AOT.

Comment: Had a similar issue and I want to emphasize this is what fixed my problem: "1. Make sure you only import NgReduxModule in app.module.ts"